# Which one is better Push notification for IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am developing an chat application for Android and IOS in Ionic. Now I am trying to implement the `Push Notification` for both devices. While doing google I found lot of Push services to implement. **GCM**(Google Cloud Messaging) now latest of GCM is **FCM**(Firebase Cloud Messaging) one anther service is [OneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs)

So which one is better so that single code work for both devices like android and ios.

Comment: GCM was best. The main problem with FCM is push does not hit onMessageReceived() when app is in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand. It inherits GCM’s core infrastructure, with new SDKs to make Cloud Messaging development easier.

Benefits of upgrading to FCM SDK include:

> Simpler client development. You no longer have to write your own
>   registration or subscription retry logic. An out-of-the-box
>   notification solution. You can use Firebase Notifications, a
>   serverless notifications solution with a web console that lets anyone
>   send notifications to target specific audiences based on Firebase
>   Analytics insights.

Source URL : https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#gcm-fcm

Some features of GCM is already depreciated and now in coming days GCM are going to fully depreciated. But Google says We will continue to support the current version of GCM Android and iOS SDKs because we know a lot of developers are using GCM SDKs today to handle notifications, and client app upgrade takes time.

But all new client-side features will be added to FCM SDKs only moving forward. You are strongly encouraged to upgrade to FCM SDKs.

Source URL :  https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq

Answer (score -2):

Firebase is the latest project. GCM is deprecated.

Firebase supports iOS (Swift 3) & Android

Comment: According to this FAQ https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq, they said: "We will continue to support the current version of GCM Android and iOS SDKs because we know a lot of developers are using GCM SDKs today to handle notifications, and client app upgrade takes time."

Comment: Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features! See the FAQ to learn more. If you are integrating messaging in a new app, start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM, in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.